# How to exclude files from a project in PhpStorm by pattern?

Tags: phpstorm, projects-and-solutions

I'm using PhpStorm 10.0.1.  I want to exclude files in directories that match a pattern.  I want this exclusion to remove the excluded files from the set of files that PhpStorm uses when - for example - finding duplicate definitions of classes.

I've gotten part of the way through the solution, which involves Scopes:

- Open a project in PhpStorm
- Go to Settings (File -> Settings)
- Navigate to Appearance & Behavior -> Scopes
- Create a scope to exclude the appropriate file(s).

  - Click the `+` icon
  - Select either Local or Shared
  - Give the scope a name
  - Enter an appropriate pattern

    - For example, to exclude files in directories that match `*-b0*`, enter `!file:*-b0*/*`
  - Click Exclude Recursively
  - Verify in the tree view that the appropriate file(s) are excluded.
  - Click OK.

This is where I'm stuck.  I can't find any reference anywhere in the UI to that named scope - except in the settings dialog where I created it.

The documentation is no help:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/scopes.html - "Scopes" describes how to create scopes but not how to use them
- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html - "Configuring Scopes and File Colors" describes how to color files in a scope differently but not how to apply them to a project

How do I apply that scope to the current project?

(It may be the case that scopes are applied automatically.  In that case, the Scopes dialog and the rest of PhpStorm disagree on what is included and what excluded and I'll need to file a bug.)

Answer (score 3):

Scopes can be used in Project tool window - click the `Project` popup in upper left corner and choose the desired scope. They can only be used for search filtering (in `Edit/Find/Find in path` dialog), in Inspections profiles, file watchers, etc.

But note that choosing your scope in Project window is just a view option, files excluded from scope are NOT excluded from project - they will still be indexed, used in completion/navigation, etc. If you like to exclude certain files/folders completely, so that they are not included in file index, you need adding them to 'Ignore files and folders' in `Settings | Editor | File Types`. Folders can also be excluded using `Mark directory as/Excluded`

Comment: I expanded that dropdown about 10 different times, and every time it went straight from "Tests" to "Scratches" with no scopes listed between.  Now they're there.  Asking this question is what must have made them finally appear.  :)  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I've never heard of the ability to apply a custom scope globally. I believe they can only be used to allow *specific* components of PhpStorm (like code inspections & find/replace) to operate on a subset of your project's files.</strike>  Edit: This is not accurate; please see the comments below.

This hacky workaround might just do the trick, if the files you'd like to exclude from your project are never going to change:

(a) Using the pattern you've already identified, create a new custom scope that specifically *includes* the undesirable files.

(b) Perform a very broad search against that scope (`Find in Path > Scope > Custom > Custom Scopes`), so that every undesired file is matched.  You could potentially search for the text `<?php`, or use a regular expression like `.+`

(c) Create a new Favorites list, and add all of the search results to that list.

(d) From the Favorites window, highlight all of the files.  Right click them and choose "Mark as plain text".  This will prevent PhpStorm from indexing them, so they'll no longer be considered by the IDE's static code analysis.

Comment: It seems that it at least *used* to be possible: the comments at the bottom of https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/excluding-files-from-project.html include some from a JetBrains employee (Julia Mochenkova) who describes how to do it.  Search for "Yes, you're applying Scope for the whole project".  When she says "Select your Scope from the list shown inside Project View toolbar as it shown in my previous post." she's referring to "Does this picture help? http://screencast.com/t/CGkCz4e5o ".  But I'm not finding that scopes dropdown anywhere. (1/2)

Comment: Maybe it was removed from the product between then and now.  I'd ask on their forum, but it seems to be populated by crickets and not JetBrains employees.  (2/2)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new today!  It looks like this feature is definitely still a part of PhpStorm 10.  If the project toolbar isn't already visible, go to `View > Tool Windows > Project`.  Then click on the text "Project" that appears directly above the root folder of the directory tree.  From there, you should be able to select your custom scope!

Comment: I checked that dropdown about 10 different times and no scopes were listed, so I assumed the feature was removed.  But sure enough, they're (eventually) there.  Thanks for your help!